# How to return the logarithmic equation of data set

Tags: python

I am trying to do a very simple task which is to replicate an excel task in python which is to return the logarithmic equation of a curve in python. When I used the below values I was able to get an equation of y = -1271ln(x) + 12235.  I would like to use python to return this equation with the data set below. I am not sure what library or function would allow me to do this.  Thanks

```
price = np.array([2500,2300,2100,1900,1700,1500,1300])
demand = np.array([2070,2487,2943,3444,4002,4629,5346])
```

Comment: What Excel code did you use?

Comment: @wjandrea I just placed the values in a columns then inserted a scatter plot from the data then added a logarithmic trend line and displayed the equation on the chart